# How to Map MS SQL date to Instant JPA

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have an Entity as follows

```
@Entity
public class Requirement {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "DocUpdatedDate")
    private Instant docUpdatedDate;
}
```

I have used Instant in place of Date. This code fails with error as below:-

```
  | Hibernate: select cdmdocumen0_.ID as ID1_0_, cdmdocumen0_.DocCategory as DocCateg2_0_, cdmdocumen0_.DocExpirationDate as DocExpir3_0_, cdmdocumen0_.DocRequirement as DocRequi4_0_, cdmdocumen0_.DocType as DocType5_0_, cdmdocumen0_.DocUpdatedDate as DocUpdat6_0_, cdmdocumen0_.DocURI as DocURI7_0_, cdmdocumen0_.LEID as LEID8_0_, cdmdocumen0_.Status as Status9_0_ from ibof.vwCdmDocumentRequirement cdmdocumen0_ where cdmdocumen0_.ID in (select max(cdmdocumen1_.ID) from ibof.vwCdmDocumentRequirement cdmdocumen1_ where LEID=? and (STATUS not in  (? , ?)) group by leid , DocCategory , DocType , DocRequirement)
  | 2018-02-26 04:01:08.120 ERROR 6 --- [pool-4-thread-1] o.s.s.s.TaskUtils$LoggingErrorHandler    : Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task.
  | 
  | org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not deserialize; nested exception is org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not deserialize
  |    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:333) ~[spring-orm-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.13.RELEASE]
  |    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:244) ~[spring-orm-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.13.RELEASE]
  |    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:503) ~[spring-orm-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.13.RELEASE]
  |    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59) ~[spring-tx-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.13.RELEASE]
  |    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:209) ~[spring-tx-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.13.RELEASE]
  |    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147) ~[spring-tx-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.13.RELEASE]
  |    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.13.RELEASE]
  |    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:133) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.9.RELEASE.jar!/:?]
  |    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.13.RELEASE]
  |    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.13.RELEASE]
  |    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.13.RELEASE]
  |    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:57) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.9.RELEASE.jar!/:?]
  |    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.13.RELEASE]
  |    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213) ~[spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.13.RELEASE]
  |    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy117.findByLeIdAndStatus(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
  |    at com.aurotfp.cdc.integration.fenergo.service.FenergoService.getDocumentMatrix(FenergoService.java:176) ~[classes!/:?]
  |    at com.aurotfp.cdc.integration.fenergo.service.FenergoService.syncLegalEntity(FenergoService.java:78) ~[classes!/:?]
  |    at com.aurotfp.cdc.integration.fenergo.service.SyncLegalEntity.lambda$sync$0(SyncLegalEntity.java:37) ~[classes!/:?]
  |    at java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
  |    at com.aurotfp.cdc.integration.fenergo.service.SyncLegalEntity.sync(SyncLegalEntity.java:37) ~[classes!/:?]
  |    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
  |    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
  |    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
  |    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
  |    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:65) ~[spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.13.RELEASE]
  |    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) [spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.13.RELEASE]
  |    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81) [spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.13.RELEASE]
  |    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [?:1.8.0_151]
  |    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [?:1.8.0_151]
  |    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [?:1.8.0_151]
  |    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) [?:1.8.0_151]
  |    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_151]
  |    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_151]
  |    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_151]
  | Caused by: org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not deserialize
  |    at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper.doDeserialize(SerializationHelper.java:243) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
  |    at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper.deserialize(SerializationHelper.java:287) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
  |    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.SerializableTypeDescriptor.fromBytes(SerializableTypeDescriptor.java:138) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
  |    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.SerializableTypeDescriptor.wrap(SerializableTypeDescriptor.java:113) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
  |    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.SerializableTypeDescriptor.wrap(SerializableTypeDescriptor.java:27) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
  |    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.VarbinaryTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(VarbinaryTypeDescriptor.java:60) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
  |    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:47) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
  |    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:238) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
  |    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:234) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
  |    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:224) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
  |    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.hydrate(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:300) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
  |    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2790) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
  |    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadFromResultSet(Loader.java:1729) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
  |    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1655) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
  |    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1544) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
  |    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:727) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
  |    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:972) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
  |    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:930) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
  |    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:336) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
  |    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2617) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
  |    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2600) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
  |    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2429) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
  |    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2424) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
  |    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:501) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
  |    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:371) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
  |    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:216) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
  |    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1326) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
  |    at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:87) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
  |    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:606) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
  |    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:483) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
  |    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
  |    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
  |    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
  |    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
  |    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$DeferredQueryInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:372) ~[spring-orm-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.13.RELEASE]
  |    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy129.getResultList(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
  |    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$CollectionExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:123) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.9.RELEASE.jar!/:?]
  |    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:87) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.9.RELEASE.jar!/:?]
  |    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:116) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.9.RELEASE.jar!/:?]
  |    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:106) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.9.RELEASE.jar!/:?]
  |    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:499) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.9.RELEASE.jar!/:?]
  |    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:477) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.9.RELEASE.jar!/:?]
  |    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.13.RELEASE]
  |    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:56) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.9.RELEASE.jar!/:?]
  |    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.13.RELEASE]
  |    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.13.RELEASE]
  |    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282) ~[spring-tx-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.13.RELEASE]
  |    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.13.RELEASE]
  |    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.13.RELEASE]
  |    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136) ~[spring-tx-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.13.RELEASE]
  |    ... 28 more
  | Caused by: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 0000A7F8
  |    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:863) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
  |    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:355) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
  |    at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper$CustomObjectInputStream.<init>(SerializationHelper.java:309) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
  |    at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper$CustomObjectInputStream.<init>(SerializationHelper.java:299) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
  |    at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper.doDeserialize(SerializationHelper.java:218) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
  |    at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper.deserialize(SerializationHelper.java:287) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
  |    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.SerializableTypeDescriptor.fromBytes(SerializableTypeDescriptor.java:138) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
  |    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.SerializableTypeDescriptor.wrap(SerializableTypeDescriptor.java:113) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
  |    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.SerializableTypeDescriptor.wrap(SerializableTypeDescriptor.java:27) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
  |    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.VarbinaryTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(VarbinaryTypeDescriptor.java:60) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
  |    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:47) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
  |    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:238) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
  |    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:234) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
  |    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:224) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
  |    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.hydrate(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:300) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
  |    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2790) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
  |    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadFromResultSet(Loader.java:1729) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
  |    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1655) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
  |    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1544) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
  |    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:727) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
  |    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:972) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
  |    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:930) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
  |    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:336) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
  |    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2617) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
  |    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2600) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
  |    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2429) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
  |    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2424) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
  |    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:501) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
  |    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:371) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
  |    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:216) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
  |    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1326) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
  |    at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:87) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
  |    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:606) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
  |    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:483) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
  |    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
  |    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
  |    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
  |    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
  |    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$DeferredQueryInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:372) ~[spring-orm-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.13.RELEASE]
  |    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy129.getResultList(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
  |    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$CollectionExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:123) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.9.RELEASE.jar!/:?]
  |    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:87) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.9.RELEASE.jar!/:?]
  |    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:116) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.9.RELEASE.jar!/:?]
  |    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:106) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.9.RELEASE.jar!/:?]
  |    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:499) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.9.RELEASE.jar!/:?]
  |    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:477) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.9.RELEASE.jar!/:?]
  |    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.13.RELEASE]
  |    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:56) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.9.RELEASE.jar!/:?]
  |    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.13.RELEASE]
  |    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.13.RELEASE]
  |    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282) ~[spring-tx-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.13.RELEASE]
  |    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.13.RELEASE]
  |    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.13.RELEASE]
  |    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136) ~[spring-tx-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.13.RELEASE]
  |    ... 28 more
  |
```

**Database used :** MS SQL

I know i could manage it by using getter and setter. But is there a cleaner way of doing it by using JPA / Spring data.

Comment: Do you have the `hibernate-java8` support package included?

Comment: Nope! I don' t think so

Comment: What is your Hibernate version?

Comment: I am using spring boot version 1.x which supports hibernate version 4.0. so either I will have to use converter or explicitly specify JSRconveter in component scan